# Sorting columns of a matrix according to a particular row in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a simple way to sort matrix in c++ according to eg. first row, so that all elements rearrange accordingly?

Example:

```
int matrix[3][3] = { {5,2,4},
                     {1,7,8},
                     {9,2,6} };
```

After sorting by first row it would look like this:

```
{2,4,5},
{7,8,1},
{2,6,9}
```

Preferably, I'd like to use sort() function, and I don't mind using vectors if it would make the task easier.

Comment: You basically want to sort the columns. You can easily sort rows, but not columns. You may want to transpose first, then sort.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. thx for clarification. I'll look it up.

Comment: The other method is to not sort the matrix itself, but only sort an array of indices that indicate where the sorted items will be placed.  Then rebuild the matrix based on the indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments said, it's easier to sort a matrix by a column than by a row, since `std::sort` with the use of a lambda function will do the job for the former.

My recommendation is to sort the column indices by the row, then use the sorted indices to rebuild the matrix:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
const int n = 3; // size of matrix
int sort_by_row = 0; // row to sort by
int original[n][n] = { {5,2,4},
                        {1,7,8},
                        {9,2,6} };
int main() {
    int col_indices[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) col_indices[i] = i; // create column indices 0...n-1
    sort(col_indices, col_indices + n, [] (const int &a, const int &b) { // sort indices by row
        return original[sort_by_row][a] < original[sort_by_row][b];
    });
    
    int sorted[n][n]; // rebuild matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sorted[i][j] = original[i][col_indices[j]];
        }
    }
}
```

In this method, you iterate over the matrix once only, whereas if you transpose the matrix, sort, then transpose it back, you iterate over the matrix twice (during transposition).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was searching for and explanation is clear enough.